# creating subset (using a col of data frame) using for loop and finding unique values of another column

Tags: r

I am new to R and am stuck up solving a problem. Could anyone point out where I have gone wrong
I have the following data*

```
   Score    TestID
   1536      2
   16000     18000
   1         15
   7         1800 
   738       256
```

There are 25000 Test IDs and each TestID has an associated score. In this case the score ranges from 0 to 16000. I need to plot a graph of the number of unique TestIDs that are present in a particular range i.e

```
  ScoreRange      # of unique TestId
  0 - 16000              ?
  10 - 16000             ?
  20 - 16000             ?
     .                   . 
     .                   .
```

I have written a code wherein I am considering a step size of 10 (for range) and finding out the unique TestIDs in that range. Though I have not come up to plotting, I am struggling to get the output in the format described above.

```
    final <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = length(seq(1,max(Combined$Score),         
    10)))


     for (i in seq(1,max(df$Score), 10)) {
     comp <- subset(Combined, Score >= i)
     unik <- length(unique(comp$TestID))
     final[,c(1,2)] <- c(i,unik)

    }
```

I get a very weird output for final which is essentially two values repeating over. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Your issue is that when you write the result of your for loop into the "final" matrix, you don't specify which row of the matrix to write the results to.  To fix this, I create a "counter" variable, and set it equal to 0 before your for loop, then add 1 to it for each iteration of the loop.  The counter indicates which row of the matrix to write the result to.  Try this:

```
final <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = length(seq(0,max(Combined$Score),         
    10)))
counter<-0
for (i in seq(0,max(df$Score), 10)) {
  counter<-counter+1
  comp <- subset(df, Score >= i)
  unik <- length(unique(comp$TestID))
  final[counter,c(1,2)] <- c(i,unik)

}
```

Comment: Assume the Score is arranged in ascending order: 0-16000
How many unique TestIDs would I find in score range 0-10, 0-20, ........0-16000. Let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: I'm still a little bit unclear on the ranges, do you want every range to end at 16000, and to go up by 10 each time? Regardless, I believe that should just be a matter of modifying the "seq()" statement and the rest of my code should work. Let me know if any of it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ideally I would have wanted the step size to be 1 but I am experimenting from 1 to 100. I know that it would be a monotonically decreasing function but would want to plot a graph to see the same.

Comment: Okay I figured out where your original code went wrong.  You were really close, but when you wrote your answer to your final matrix, you didn't specify what row to write the results to, so each iteration of your loop just overwrote the last result.  Check out my edit to your code, this should work.

Comment: Thanks a ton !!! This worked like a charm and also thanks for explaining the solution !!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you might consider is generating a histogram with `hist()`. Using the `breaks` parameter may provide the flexibility with step size you mentioned. Anyway, I created a mini version of `Combined` as an example:

```
Combined <- data.frame(Score = sample(0:16000,15),
                       TestID = sample(0:25000,15))
> Combined
   Score TestID
1  11456  14802
2  15854   1575
3  13738  22466
4   1659  14022
5  10671   4213
   ...    ...

Combined.hist <- hist(Combined$Score,
                      breaks = seq(0,16000))
final <- data.frame(Score = Combined.hist$breaks,
                    Counts = c(length(Combined[Combined$Score == 0]$Score),
                               Combined.hist$counts))
```